# How to simulate keyboard key press (+Code ASCII of 'ALT' key)

Tags: linux, keyboard-events

I recently understood that if I write characters inside */dev/tty* it will simulate key presses with a keyboard.

I was wondering if I can simulate holding a key or a key combination.

What I'm looking for is to simulate the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between open applications.
I'm not looking for alternatives. I am practising to learn how can I simulate a physical key press on a keyboard.
Is it possible to simulate key combinations (like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>)?

Also, how can I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

It seems it's not '\n' or '\r' or "\r\n" or "\n\r".
The reason I'm looking for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is that I want do a "sudo" command in the terminal and when it prompts for a password, I use the */dev/tty* to answer that, but it seems standard input or standard output (using "-S" option with sudo) don't work.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
Are there some libraries I should be looking for (like [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect))? Or is what I'm trying to do impossible?

I am using C++. All I want to do is to try to simulate a physical key press on my keyboard. The OS is [Ubuntu 13.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_13.04_.28Raring_Ringtail.29) (Raring Ringtail). (Just as a practise)

But I have two goals:

1. To create a program which switches between applications using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. interact with a Linux terminal.

I've found two solutions:

1. Write characters/codeASCII s of the corresponding keys to */dev/tty*
2. Write characters/codeASCII s of the corresponding keys to standard output and/or standard input

But none of them worked. Is what I'm doing correct or not?

Comment: you're not saying what do you want… is it for Xorg? it looks like it as you want "alt-tab" to work… What programming language do you want to use? What did you try so far? It looks to me like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/224770): you're having a problem, you think you got the solution, you ask about the solution, whereas your solution is totally wrong hiding what could be a valid problem instead. This post is going to be closed as "Too Broad", and please prepare a new, better question, with your real problem this time. I'm not down voting because you're new to the site.

Comment: @zmo thanks ! I provided some more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X does not read keystrokes from `/dev/tty`.  If you want to simulate keystrokes in X, you’ll need to send them another way.  If you’re writing a shell script, [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) is your friend; if you’re writing C, though, you’ll probably want to use [libxdo](http://www.semicomplete.com/files/xdotool/docs/html/), the library underlying xdotool.  If you’re looking for something a bit more low-level, you might be interested in the [XCB Test API](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/manual/group__XCB__Test__API.html), on which both xdotool and libxdo rely.

Unless you can provide more information about your experience with sudo, I don’t think anybody will be able to answer your second question.  `sudo -S` is definitely the intended mechanism for programmatically providing a password to sudo.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin !
What I was trying to do was to tell the terminal to do this command after two hours (when I'm asleep) : "sudo apt-get install gobjc" BUT as you know it asks for password . I wanted to interactively give it the password and a <enter> key inside XTerm .

Comment: You could do `sudo /bin/sh -c 'sleep 2h; apt-get -y install gobjc'`.

Comment: gosh I was looking for years for such "libxdo", found out that both https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/xdo/0.0.4 and https://github.com/rshk/python-libxdo  just works. Than, @BenjaminBarenblat